# Setting environment variable type to REG_EXPAND_SZ using Powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am stuck on a issue. I am trying to set user-environment variables using PowerShell:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($key,$value,'User')
```

But when I look into the registry I can see the new entry is of type `REG_SZ`.

I would like it to be of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: btw, you should be using double quotes to delimit your powershell variables. if you don't, they will be treated as literals; you will have $key as the key name instead of the _value_ of $key as the name.

Comment: The question has been edited to address @x0n's astute observation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace for Registry [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=net-6.0#methods). To set the data type, use [RegistryValueKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=net-6.0) enumeration. Like so:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment","MyKey","1",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
```

User variables are located in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`

System variables are located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

Comment: I will immediately try it out and thanks for the quick reply really appreciated :-)

Comment: Wow ur solution was spot on hats off to you :-) But just one more question How can I do this for another user - for eg - I am logged as user A and want to set the user environment for User B ?

Comment: You don't access another user's registry easily. Consider what could happen if one can just insert arbitary keys to another user's, say, `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` location.Either run the script as User B via login script or the like, or use a system variable.

Comment: @ajax You could always load the hive of the other user, given you have the appropriate level of access. This way you can even "prime" the other users' environments. However, the usual way to achieve it would be to manipulate the system-wide environment instead.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment $key $value -Type ExpandString
```

Or golfed

```sh
sp hkcu:environment $key $value -t e
```

[Set-ItemProperty sets Registry Value as String on some systems instead of DWord, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16787365/#16790391)