# Why doesn't shell %variable% work when set from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

I am inserting a variable string in my `PATH` variable. I set the variables in following manner:

```
$var="MyTestPath"
$mypath=[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",[system.environmentvariabletarget]::User) 
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST",$var,[system.environmentvariabletarget]::User)
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",$mypath+";%TEST%",[system.environmentvariabletarget]::User)
```

The above code doesn't work for me. `%TEST%` variable doesn't expand itself when I check the path in the new shell. It shows new path ending with `%TEST%`. This has always worked when I set this from GUI or from Windows shell prompt. Why is this behavior different when variables are set from PowerShell? Is this feature removed in PowerShell?

I **don't want** to do the following, because it will keep adding my variable to path everytime I run the script.

```
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",$mypath+";"+$var,[system.environmentvariabletarget]::User)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try  change this line:

```
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",$mypath+";%TEST%",[system.environmentvariabletarget]::User)
```

with:

```
$test =[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("test","user") # this retrieve the rigth variable value
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $mypath +";$test",[system.environmentvariabletarget]::User)
```

`%test%` have no meaning in powershell, can't be expandend as in CMD.

`$env:test` retrive only from system environment variable and not from user

Comment: above added `;%TEST%` at the end of my path and it didn't expand to its value.

Comment: Thanks @Christian. I mentioned in my question that i don't want to take that approach. Everytime I run the script, this will keep appending previous `PATH` to new `PATH`. (`$mypath` is read from user `path`  variable). I want to set `PATH=somepath;%TEST%` just one time and keep changing the `TEST` as and when I need thus changing `PATH` automatically. But since `cmd` is not able to expand `%TEST%`  this is not wrokging for me. I hope this is not confusing.

Comment: @Alok You can check if `path` variable contains `$var` before setting it to `path` variable to avoid repetions each script's execution. This If I understood well your needs. Good luck

Comment: Its not very simple to remove the $var easily. var consists of atleast 15 different paths. Sometimes I change existing path in var in which case i have to maintain old var and new var which will complicate things. I don't want `powershell` to expand `%TEST%` but i just want to set `path` as `somepath;%TEST%`. For `powershell` this is just a string, but when I open `CMD terminal` i expect this variable to be expanded but it doesn't happen. This is something confusing for me. Why does `cmd` differentiate between `%TEST%` when set from GUI or cmd vs when we set same string from `powershell`

Comment: I guess this question is more for `windows shell` community rather than for `powershell` community.  `powershell` is behaving as expected but `windows shell` is not behaving normally. I am hoping someone has experienced this before.

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to effectively set a registry value (that corresponds to a env var) that uses REG_EXPAND_SZ.  See this [post for details on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294318/setting-environemnt-type-to-reg-expand-sz-using-powershell).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Keith. I tried to set registry variable using the approach in the link. I set my `TEST` variable as `[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment","TEST","MyTestString",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)` Interestingly, powershell is returning me correct value of this variable, but if i open a new windows shell and look for value of `TEST` using `echo %TEST%`, it is returning an old value. I guess i will have to understand further where windows shell reads the value of `TEST` variable from, when it expands `%TEST%`.