# Set-ItemProperty sets Registry Value as String on some systems instead of DWord, why?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, dword

I try to create an item using `Set-ItemProperty` in PowerShell, which works on most systems:

```
New-PSDrive -name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCR:\Software\MyCompany\ -Name Level -Value 5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This creates a DWORD-value on most Windows 7 systems, but I have found one system where this creates a STRING-value instead, and I want to know: why? What could happen that the systems behave differently? All don't have that value already set, all use the same base image using the same Powershell version.

Btw, I found that by using the following code, I can explicitly set a type, so I already solved the problem:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCR:\Software\MyCompany\ -Name Level -Value 5 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PropertyType DWord
```

But just for curiosity, I want to know why the systems behave differently.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't have an answer to why it happens but to avoid such instances, be explicit. Use the Type (dynamic) Parameter and specify a [RegistryValueKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind.aspx) value (you can also use it with `New-ItemProperty`) :

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCR:\Software\MyCompany -Name Level -Value 5 -Type DWord
```

Comment: Is the `-Type` documented anywhere?

Comment: @MadTomVane It appears to be a registry-provider-specific thing.  I couldn't find further documentation but [this article](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/powershell-registry-set-itemproperty-gotchas/) was useful for me.

Comment: "Type" appears to be invalid in Windows 10. Also Colon after "HKCR" is invalid.

Comment: If PowerShell gives you an error on `-Type` try to use path's short form. Instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...` try `HKLM:\...`. Works as of today with Windows 10 v20H2 b19042.1052

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\MyCompany","Level",5,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord)
```

Comment: This works well for older powershell versions where for some odd reason the -type parameter doesnt seem to exist.

Comment: Note that you have to specify the decimal value here instead of the hex value.