# How can I discover parameter attributes for dynamic parameters?

Tags: powershell, dynamic, parameters, attributes

The command `Set-ItemProperty` [has a dynamic parameter named `Type` that is important for the Windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790391/1404637).  Invoking `Get-Help Set-ItemProperty` does not mention the `Type` parameter.  I *think* this omission occurs because `Type` is a dynamic parameter.

I would like to discover the `Type` parameter's attributes.  In particular, I would like to know whether the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` argument is set.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd hklm:
(Get-Command Set-ItemProperty).ParameterSets.parameters

Name                            : Type
ParameterType                   : Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind
IsMandatory                     : False
IsDynamic                       : True
Position                        : -2147483648
ValueFromPipeline               : False
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName : True
ValueFromRemainingArguments     : False
HelpMessage                     : 
Aliases                         : {}
Attributes                      : {__AllParameterSets}
```

[image]

Comment: `(Get-Command Set-ItemProperty).ParameterSets.parameters` doesn't emit any object for the `Type` parameter on my computer.  (It does output 90 other objects through.)  Are you sure that's the command you used?

Comment: Ok I got it.  The current location needs to be a registry drive.  `Push-Location HKLM:; (Get-Command Set-ItemProperty).ParameterSets.parameters | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Type'}; Pop-Location` works.

Comment: Here's an alternative if you want to avoid changing location. `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Set-ItemProperty', 'Cmdlet', 'HKLM:\').Parameters.Type`.  The third parameter in `GetCommand` is an argument list.